# Replacing div with another div on click

Tags: html, css, angularjs, servicenow

I've built a widget in ServiceNow that displays a user's onboarding steps and when a step is clicked upon, a div appears below that lists out all of the tasks that they need to complete.  While this works fine, I think it would look slicker if instead of having a div appear below the onboarding steps with a line divider, that the list of tasks would take the place of the entire onboarding steps div.  Then maybe have a back button that takes them back to the onboarding steps with some fade in/fade out animation.  If possible, I would like this to be done without jquery.  Can someone provide some guidance or direct me towards an example?

My HTML so far looks like this:

```
<div class="container" ng-if="!c.data.loading && c.stage.length>0">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ng-repeat="item in c.stage track by $index">
      <div class="at-work-process position-relative overflow-hidden text-center">
        <div class="at-work-process-text">
          <span class="at-work-process-step" ng-class="{inactive: item.workflow_order>c.currentOrder}">Step</span>
          <span class="at-work-process-number" ng-class="{inactive: item.workflow_order>c.currentOrder}">{{$index+1}}</span>
          <span class="at-work-process-number-text" ng-class="{inactive: item.workflow_order>c.currentOrder}">{{item.workflow_stage}}</span>
          <div class="at-separator-thick" ng-class="{active_stage: item.currentStage, completed_stage: item.incompleteTotal==0 && item.workflow_order<c.currentOrder}"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-click="showDetails(item);" class="at-work-process-details" ng-class="{inactive: item.workflow_order>c.currentOrder}">          
          <div ng-if="item.incompleteTotal>0 && item.workflow_order<=c.currentOrder" class="full-height">
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:#e53935;">assignment_late</i>
            <span ng-if="item.incompleteTotal>1">Incomplete <br/> {{item.incompleteTotal}} Tasks Require Your Attention</span>
            <span ng-if="item.incompleteTotal==1">Incomplete <br/> {{item.incompleteTotal}} Task Require Your Attention</span>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="item.incompleteTotal==0 && item.workflow_order>c.currentOrder" class="full-height">
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:#78B4F3;">assignment</i>
            <span>Not Started</span>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="item.incompleteTotal==0 && item.workflow_order<c.currentOrder" class="full-height">
            <i class="material-icons" style="color:#43A047;">assignment_turned_in</i>
            <span>Complete</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

**//am hoping the below div would take the place of the above div instead of showing up underneath it//**

```
  <div ng-if="active_tasks.length>0" ng-class="taskClass" class="text-center tasksDiv">
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <h3>{{active_workflow}} Tasks:</h3>
    <ul style="list-style:none; padding-left:0; display:inline-block">
      <li ng-repeat="tasks in active_tasks track by $index" style="display:flex; align-items:center; padding-bottom:0.5rem;">
        <i class="material-icons" style={{tasks.style}}>{{tasks.icon}}</i>
        <a ng-if="tasks.url.indexOf('table2')!=-1" ng-click="c.enroll(tasks)" href="javascript: void(0)" ng-class="{completed_inactive: tasks.state==3}">{{tasks.short_description}}</a>
        <a ng-if="tasks.url.indexOf('table1')!=-1" ng-click="c.tableNew()" href="javascript: void(0)"ng-class="{completed_inactive: tasks.state==3}">{{tasks.short_description}}</a>
        <a ng-if="tasks.hr_task_type=='url' && tasks.url.indexOf('c.')==-1" href="{{tasks.url}}" target="_blank" ng-class="{completed_inactive: tasks.state==3}">{{tasks.short_description}}</a>
                <a ng-if="tasks.url.indexOf('launchWith')!=-1" ng-click="c.launchWith()" href="javascript: void(0)" ng-class="{completed_inactive: tasks.state==3}">{{tasks.short_description}}</a>
        <a ng-if="tasks.hr_task_type!='url'" ng-click="review(tasks)" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_blank" ng-class="{completed_inactive: tasks.state==3}">{{tasks.short_description}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attach an ng-if to the first div that works on the opposite condition of the second div.

So in this case, your second div has `ng-if="active_tasks.length>0"` as its condition for display. So you could set an `ng-if="active_tasks.length<=0"` on the first div so that any time the second div is displayed, the condition will be false for the first div. Then just remove the divider in the second div (since you don't want that anymore). Now when you perform an action on the first div and `active_tasks` gets populated, the first one will be destroyed and the second one will be created.

Note that in this case, you're using `ng-if` which will create/destroy DOM elements. You can also use `ng-show` to show/hide the DOM elements if you anticipate the user going back and for a lot (so that they're created up front and just hidden instead of being recreated each time the user changes the state)

Comment: whoa, amazing thanks!  if i wanted to create a back button that takes me back to just the onboarding list view, how would I do that?  I assume I need an ng-click that toggles to show active_tasks.length>0 again right?

Comment: Yep, you would want to clear the list  to meet that condition. The other choice here would probably be to do something like what Tyler suggested below and create a separate boolean/state object to track where you are instead of using the list size. This lets you keep the list populated (and populate up front).

Answer (score 1):

Your html is slightly hard to follow, so I'm not sure which blocks you would like to hide/show, but you can do this very simply. Just create a variable, `showTaskList` on your scope and set it to `true/false`. Then on the parent div for the onboarding list do, `ng-if="!showTaskList"` and on the parent div for the task list, `ng-if="showTaskList"`.

When the person clicks the button to switch between the task list or the onboarding steps, just switch this bool to the opposite, `showTaskList = !showTaskList`.